# Synaptics Touchpad and TrackPoint are disabled only when I am logged in

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, synaptics-touchpad

Synaptics touchpad works without issues on the logon screen. But when I log in, it gets disabled immediately. After locking the computer using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (i.e. after temporarily leaving the session) it is immediately enabled again until I unlock the session. I did not play with any settings. Any help?

Its control panel currently looks completely disabled like this:

[image]

Comment: If you have permissions to create another user, create a temporary one and check if this user can use trackpad.

Comment: @Ramhound – everything was working few days ago including enabled control panel.

Comment: @Roh_mish – finally, reinstalling the drivers helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fixed by reinstalling drivers.

The issue got corrected immediately after drivers setup program finished its work. The functionality is stable after computer restart, too.

**Details:**

I visited Lenovo Support page and searched for my laptop model. Then I downloaded **Synaptics ThinkPad UltraNav Driver for Windows 10 (32-bit, 64-bit) - ThinkPad** and started the installer. (I made no uninstallation of prior drivers.) No matter the installed drivers were the same version as current ones, the installer perhaps fixed some Registry settings and that helped. The **ThinkPad** tab in **Mouse Properties** control panel shown above got re-enabled again.